# Why am I seeing a white line on my vs code screen?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am seeing a white line on my vs code window all of a sudden after the last update. It's not my display error. I am not seeing the line on any other application. Just in visual studio code.

Does anyone know the reason?
[image: Click here to see a screenshot]

Comment: its the recommended maximum width of the language you're typing in. It's a reminder to press enter basically.

Comment: @nordmanden how do I remove it, mate?

Answer (score 1):

Preferences -> Settings
Search Editor Rulers

should be like this

"editor.rulers": [
80
]

make like this
"editor.rulers": []

Comment: That didn't work mate

Comment: try increasing the value betwen [] on editor.rulers to a higher value, if null didn't work, i don't know on your case, but put a higher value

Comment: Still remains the same